# Dart base64 decoding

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my base64 encoded String :

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZXNzaW9uSWQiOiJkMjNiN2ViMy03MDgyLTRkZDktOGQ0OC1lMjU2YTM3OTNiOTciLCJyZWZyZXNoVG9rZW4iOiJiN2M3MTc4Yi04OWRjLTQxMDctYjUzNC1hOGZiOTNhMzEwNzAiLCJuYW1lIjoiTGVuIiwiaWF0IjoxNTczMDI4MjU2fQ
```

Using https://jwt.io/ it decodes correctly
But When trying to use `base64.decode('--Base64String--);` in Flutter it gives me these errors

```
FormatException: Invalid character (at character 37)
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZXNzaW9uSWQiOiIzYWNiNzBjZS0wYzYxLT...
```

When removing the string in front of the `.` (I only need the info that comes after the `.`)
I get this error

```
FormatException: Invalid length, must be multiple of four (at character 183)
...jLTQxMDctYjUzNC1hOGZiOTNhMzEwNzAiLCJuYW1lIjoiTGVuIiwiaWF0IjoxNTczMDI4MjU2fQ
```

Are there any other ways of decoding base64 encoded Strings for Dart

Comment: I use the `jose` package to deal with JWT, maybe you can give it a try

Comment: If you want to parse it yourself, split the string on `.` characters, then base64 decode the individual parts. (Then UTF-8 and JSON decode the parts to get the original data).

Answer (score 12):

You can use `base64.normalize` first.

For example:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final String b64 = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzZXNzaW9uSWQiOiJkMjNiN2ViMy03MDgyLTRkZDktOGQ0OC1lMjU2YTM3OTNiOTciLCJyZWZyZXNoVG9rZW4iOiJiN2M3MTc4Yi04OWRjLTQxMDctYjUzNC1hOGZiOTNhMzEwNzAiLCJuYW1lIjoiTGVuIiwiaWF0IjoxNTczMDI4MjU2fQ';

  String foo = b64.split('.')[0];
  List<int> res = base64.decode(base64.normalize(foo));

  print(utf8.decode(res));
}
```

Result:

```
{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}
```

Answer (score 1):

try it. This will help you

```
Center(child: 
Image.memory(
base64Decode(image6464.substring(23).replaceAll("\n", ""))
 )
),
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: this works for me. but how could base64 contain these invalid chars from the first place?

Comment: works for me somehow. but why did the string contain \n ?